# Nested Dictionary in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, nested

I want to save a data in a dictionary in below format and then have to convert it into json.

```
[{"id":"1",
"name":[{"id":"2","name":"k"},{"id":"6","name":"kk"}]",
"pass":"123"},
{"id":"2",
"name":[{"id":"2","name":"k"},{"id":"6","name":"kk"}]",
"pass":"234"}
]
```

It got dictionary and single strings both within a dictionary. Here is what I'm trying, but unable to get the desirable result.

```
var myDictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

Comment: It is not `Dictionary` it is `Array` of dictioaries

Comment: @NiravD yup. so how can i achieve this?

Comment: i'm new to swift.

Comment: There is nothing to do with Swift. It's just basic logic/coding/algorithmic stuff. Dictionary and Array are different. They can "keep" data, but their use and approach are different. Show us what you want, and we may help you.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried also you want to create array same like above there is no change in value ?

Comment: @ShahtajKhalid check out the answer and let me know if you have any confusion. :)

Comment: It's working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let arrOfData = [["id":"1","pass":"123","name":[["id":"2","name":"k"],["id":"6","name":"kk"]]],
                 ["id":"2","pass":"234","name":[["id":"2","name":"k"],["id":"6","name":"kk"]]]]
```

Here u can see the array of dictionary like `Array<Dictionary,AnyObject>` if you want to store in a single dictionary you can use it like `let dict2 = ["data":arrOfData]` Now this will convert into a single dictionary.